# Visual Studio equivalent of GDB's substitute-path (redirect source location for debug symbols)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, debug-symbols

Let's say I have a static library `Lib`, which was compiled on some other machine in directory `Z:\Lib` with debug symbols.
As a result static library `Lib` has debug symbols which point to sources in `Z:\Lib`.

Let's say I'm debugging an application which was linked with `Lib`. When I step into a function of `Lib`, I see only disassembly (not source code), where as I'd like to see sources of `Lib`, which are located in `C:\Lib` on my PC.

Is it possible to specify substitute path (from `Z:\Lib` to `C:\Lib`) for debug symbols in Visual Studio?

Comment: Right-click the Solution node in the Solution Explorer window > Properties > Common Properties > Debug Source Files.  No need to do this up-front, the debugger prompts you for the directory when it can't find a source file.

Comment: @HansPassant, what if I am not using VS solution, but opening a project using "Open a local folder" option? (I have a CMake project)

Comment: Please use `add_subdirectory(C:\Lib)` on the `CMakeLists.txt` file.